# Remove access to application pages

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

What is the best way to remove access to application pages in one zone only. The web application is extended with multiple zones

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to CA->Application management->Manage web applications->check the web application, click permission policy->Add permission policy level named "Deny view application pages"->choose deny "View application pages" permission:

[image]

Then Navigate to CA->Application management->Manage web applications->check the web application, click user policy->Add users->select the zone->set a user with "Deny view application pages" permission:

[image]

Comment: Hi Lisa, this works, however i need to disable access to any pages under _layouts, e.g. _layouts/viewlists.aspx, _layouts/settings.aspx